# Transformation of a variable to follow Normality

Tags: transformation

When I plotted histogram of a variable to see whether it follows normality, I got a highly positive skewed graph, more like that of a poisson/exponential distribution.

Now, what kind of transformation should I do on the variable to make it follow normality?

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer to that question; and at any rate it belongs on a statistics site more than a programming site. Maybe http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?